# What's the point in using RenderBeginTag & RenderEndTag

Tags: asp.net

Custom controls can use this for example to render out a span tag:

```
writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);  
writer.Write(Text);  
writer.RenderEndTag();
```

Ok, why can't I just do this:

```
writer.Write("<span>");
writer.Write(Text);
writer.Write(</span>");
```

this way I can actually see it rather than reading HtlmlTextWriter tags all over the place and also tweak any of the mark-up easily such as adding cs classes, ids, or whaetver to the tags.  And if you say it's faster to type because of Intellisense, is that about the only reason to use RenderBegin and RenderEnd?  that's not much of a case.

Comment: so does anyone not use this and writes out the HTML like I have above just for at least for me it's more maintainable and readable?  Anyone feel the same here?

Answer (score 5):

Here where I work, we use the RenderBeginTag()/RenderEndTag() technique exclusively in our large suite of custom controls, and generally eschew calling Write("") directly.  There are several good reasons:

- As Patrick noted, by using RenderBeginTag()/RenderEndTag(), you can't accidentally emit elements with typos in their names.
- With RenderBeginTag()/RenderEndTag(), the ASP.NET runtime will tell you if you've emitted bad markup --- if you forget a matching RenderEndTag() for a previous RenderBeginTag(), ASP.NET will throw an exception on your page.  This makes it really hard to have an unclosed element.
- Likewise, you can't mismatch closing tags this way either --- <div> must be ended with </div>, and cannot be accidentally ended with </span>.
- The AddAttribute() method allows rendering of complex single elements to be divided up into logical chunks:  This method adds appropriate CSS classnames, that one correctly computes the *value* attribute, and that method over there adds a special custom *foo* attribute.  Doing that kind of element assembly with a StringBuilder is possible, but it can be more error-prone.
- Tools can automatically and reliably find usages for you.  If I want to know every line of code in our controls that emits, say, a span, I can just search for usages of HtmlTextWriterTag.Span.  Searching on "<span" is a bit more error-prone, and may miss some usages if the "<" is written out separately from the "span" (as would be the case in a control that switches back and forth between a *span* and an *a* element depending an *Enabled* flag).
- Extension methods can expand on the AddAttribute() method to add attributes in more sophisticated ways:  We have an AddNonNullClassnames() extension method that constructs the *class* attribute from any of the multiple strings that are passed in that are neither null nor empty, and it's proven a godsend in building complicated controls that are still fully style-able via CSS.
- ASP.NET will attempt (*attempt*, I say) to perform proper indentation of the output based on how deeply nested the elements are.  It doesn't always succeed, but its result is better for debugging than just having all your HTML emitted on one line, or smashed up against the left column.

(For the record, we use pure-CSS layouts --- no table-based layouts on *my* watch, thank you! --- and these techniques have helped with that too.)

I was pretty resistive of this at first myself --- it's long, and wordy, and proprietary, just like you noted, and coming from an open-source background I found it pretty stinky at first --- but after three years of working with it, I can say that it makes the code more flexible, makes certain complex operations easier, and adds a surprising amount of safety and cleanliness to the output.

Answer (score 2):

You will have less typos (since `"<spsn>"` won't give a compile error, but `HtmlTextWriterTag.Spsn` will).

And perhaps not in this case, but using defined Tags will make it easier to apply changes later in code. If for some strange reason, span will be named something else, the value of the tag Span can easily be changed at one place, effectively changing all places, instead of manually changing every place where you used the string value...

Comment: Thanks Patrick, while valid points I tend to disagree.  I think that developers should use mark-up and be responsible for it.  Ignoring mark-up and delegating it to some method to me is pointless.  We as developers especially need to become better at mark-up, especially moving to tableless design.  Its because we refuse to change to tableless that our design becomes rigid for the rest of the business.

Comment: Compiler validation is a serious benefit. I definitely do not want to depend on any developer to manually encode and escape mark-up correctly, let alone misspellings and mis-casings.

Answer (score 1):

RenderBeginTag will add all attributes that you have added prior to calling it.  So it is an easy way to add attributes dynamically when writing out the html.

Comment: why can't I just write out a stringbuilder that adds attributes dynamically and then ultimately write out the string from the stringbuilder?

Comment: I guess I don't like using this syntax...it seems so proprietary and I like to see the actual mark-up so I can work with it in the custom control easier and visualize it better.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, "why can't I just write out a stringbuilder", you can of course do that, and make sure your attributes are all quoted and encoded correctly.  But you're not seriously suggesting it's easier?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other responses here, it allows the `HtmlTextWriter` to easily implement custom processing for certain tags.  For example, `Html32TextWriter` has a property `ShouldPerformDivTableSubstitution` which allows it to replace divs by tables for older user agents that only support HTML 3.2.

Probably not common these days, but still.

However I think the way it handles attributes is the most decisive benefit.  If you really think building attributes in a StringBuilder and ensuring they're quoted and encoded correctly is easier, then good luck to you!