# Render vs Write in System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter

Tags: .net, htmltextwriter

I'm programatically creating a simple HTML file which is saved directly to disk. I was looking at this example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmltextwriter

I'm confused why he mixes `HtmlTextWriter`'s `Render` and `Write` methods, and how I should choose between [`RenderBeginTag()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2a9a9ww.aspx) and [`WriteBeginTag()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.writebegintag.aspx).

Are there are hard rules on what is right & wrong?

Comment: The difference appears to be that WriteBeginTag just generates the "<tagName" string (plus indent if appropriate) whereas RenderBeginTag does a lot more work: stores the current active tag (so you don't need to specify the name in RenderEndTag), emits default attributes if present, calls events on parent text writers, etc. However I don't know enough for an answer - hopefully someone can point us to a good reference of how you use it.

Comment: If you want the rep, can you write that up as an answer @Rup

Comment: Thanks, but I know that's not the whole answer. I'd rather someone who's used RenderBeginTag etc. explained how to use it properly, and I'd vote that up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the point in using RenderBeginTag & RenderEndTag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066189/whats-the-point-in-using-renderbegintag-renderendtag)

Comment: 7 years later no one still knows the answer ?!

Answer (score -2):

Use the RenderBeginTag overload of the RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag) method if the markup element is of a known type that is one of the HtmlTextWriterTag enumeration values.

Comment: No, that - which you've copied straight out of the docs - is not relevant. That's telling you whether to choose the [tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e111b82.aspx) or the [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2a9a9ww.aspx) variants on RenderBeginTag. That's not the distinction between RenderBeginTag and WriteBeginTag.